# Configuring Baud rate on Prolific 2303HX using Rpi

Tags: pi-2, usb, uart

I am using Rpi2 for my project, I'm using Prolific 2303HX connected to my Rpi via USB without a computer.
 [image: Connection can be found here]

Green cord is connected to the GND of the Rpi and the GND in the Prolific chip

Yellow cord is connected to the Tx pin of the Prolific chip and into a scope.

I tried using this command:

```
#coding: utf-8
import time
import serial
port=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=6000000, timeout=1.0)
while True:
    port.write("a")
```

1. I received "Failed to set custom baudrate" - The prolific suppose to support up to 12Mbaud, why is this happening?

2. The system is connect to a scope so I can measure the frequency of the protocol.

My goal is to send 12Mbaud of data from my Rpi through the Tx pin on the 2303HX, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anyone? :) assistance would be highly appreciated.